# How are these equivalent representations of an ellipse?

Tags: conic-sections, legendre-polynomials

(This all started when I started to try to figure out how this first link below represents the ellipsoid with legendre polynomials)

On [this web page regarding potentials outside of a sphere](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node108.html), it begins by stating that we will represent the ellipse we are to rotate around the z-axis, with mean radius ($a=\frac{r_{minor}+r_{major}}2$ I think, although we could use the geometric mean?) as

$$r=a_{\theta}(\theta)=a(\ 1-\frac{2}{3}\epsilon P_2(\cos{(\theta)})\ )$$ where $P_2(x)$ is the second legendre polynomial,
$P_2(x)=\frac{3}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}\implies P_2(\cos{(\theta)}=\frac{3\cos^2{(\theta)}}{2}-\frac{1}{2} $ Substituting, we get
$$r=a_{\theta}(\theta)=a(1-\frac{2 \epsilon}{3}(\frac{3}{2}\cos^2{(\theta)}-\frac{1}{2})=a-\frac{2}{3}\frac{3}{2}a \epsilon \cos^2{(\theta)}+\frac{a\epsilon}{3}=\frac{a\epsilon}3+a-a \epsilon \cos^2{(\theta)}=\frac{a\epsilon}{3}+a(\frac\epsilon3+1-\epsilon\cos^2{(\theta)})$$.

However, on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center),with $\alpha$=semi-major axis, $\beta$= semi- minor axis,and eccentricity uses the same symbol as above, we are given the formula
$$r(\theta)=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2 \cos^2{(\theta)}}}$$, expanding $\epsilon$, we get 
$$r(\theta)=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\sqrt{1-(\sqrt{1-\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2}})^2\cos^2{(\theta)}}}=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\sqrt{1-1+\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2}\cos^2{(\theta)}}}=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\sqrt{1+\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2}\cos^2{(\theta)}}}$$

I'm not really seeing how to connect these two, nor am I sure which definition of $a$ is used in the first set of equations. Any suggestions? I'd rather not have it just given to me, But i'm not really sure in which direciton I should go, including what form of mean was intended. It's this "mean radius" that I've never heard of and couldn't find a standard definition with searching google. I appreciate the help in advance :)

Comment: The first curve is not an ellipse. (You also made an algebraic error there: what happened to the $\epsilon/3$ term?) Note, too, that for the first curve, the parameter $\epsilon$ is _ellipticity_, which can range over the reals, but in the second it’s _eccentricity_, which for an ellipse is in $[0,1)$ (with $0$ for a circle).

Comment: Oh, so I mixed up eccentricity and ellipticity up. I had edited the $\epsilon /3$ term in, but didn't hit save to the edits last night, my mistake. However, if it isn't an ellipse, then why does the link say that we make the oblate spheroid by rotating an ellipse about the z-axis, with its' outer boundary satisfying the first equation I posted?

Comment: That I couldn’t tell you. For ellipticity near zero, this curve is approximately elliptical. I would guess that this contour was chosen to cancel or otherwise combine nicely with an appearance of $P_2$ elsewhere.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I’ll do some more playing around later and see if I can figure it all out. Thanks

Comment: For reference, the ellipse with the same $x$- and $y$- intercepts is  $(9-12\epsilon+4\epsilon^2)x^2+(9+6\epsilon+\epsilon^2)y^2=9/a^2$.